# How to upgrade to spring-integration-kafka 2.1.0.RELEASE with xml configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am upgrading spring-integration-kafka from 1.0.0.M2 to 2.1.0.RELEASE and client 0.9.0 to 0.10.0

Current xml configuration as below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
 xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

 <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka" />

 <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
  kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext" auto-startup="true"
  channel="inputToKafka" order="1">
 </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

 <bean id="producerProperties"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="properties">
   <props>
    <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">${topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms}</prop>
    <prop key="message.send.max.retries">${message.send.max.retries}</prop>
    <prop key="send.buffer.bytes">${send.buffer.bytes}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="fcmNotificationEncoder"
  class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
  <constructor-arg value="common.vo.NotificationVo" />
 </bean>

 <int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
  producer-properties="producerProperties">
  <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
   <int-kafka:producer-configuration
    broker-list="${kafka.servers}" key-class-type="java.lang.String"
    value-class-type="common.vo.fcmNotificationVo"
    value-encoder="fcmNotificationEncoder" topic="trigger-fcm-notification"
    compression-codec="none" />
  </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
 </int-kafka:producer-context>

 <int:service-activator input-channel="ip-chanel-trigger-fcm-notification"
  ref="fcmNotificationConsumer">
 </int:service-activator>

 <bean id="consumerProperties"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="properties">
   <props>
    <prop key="auto.offset.reset">${auto.offset.reset}</prop>
    <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">${socket.receive.buffer.bytes}</prop> <!-- 10M -->
    <prop key="fetch.message.max.bytes">${fetch.message.max.bytes}</prop>
    <prop key="auto.commit.interval.ms">${auto.commit.interval.ms}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>


 <int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
  zk-connect="${zookeeper.servers}" zk-connection-timeout="${zookeeper.connection.timeout}"
  zk-session-timeout="${zookeeper.session.timeout}" zk-sync-time="${zookeeper.sync.time}" />


 <bean id="kafkaThreadListener" class="api.utils.KafkaConsumerStarter"
  init-method="initIt" destroy-method="cleanUp" />

 <int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
  kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContextFCM" auto-startup="false"
  channel="ip-chanel-trigger-fcm-notification" id="kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-FCM">
  <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
   receive-timeout="0" />
 </int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>


 <!-- Consumer -->

 <bean id="fcmNotificationDecoder"
  class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaDecoder">
  <constructor-arg value="common.vo.NotificationVo" />
 </bean>

 <int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContextFCM"
  consumer-timeout="4000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect"
  consumer-properties="consumerProperties">
  <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
   <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
    group-id="trigger-fcm-notification" max-messages="50"
    value-decoder="fcmNotificationDecoder">
    <int-kafka:topic id="trigger-fcm-notification"
     streams="10" />
   </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
  </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
 </int-kafka:consumer-context>

</beans>
```

How to change this to 2.1.0.RELEASE ?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDITED HERE:

Using reference modified the xml as per my requirement. I got small issue while reading the Consumer Record . I got payload as follows

```html
{
kafka_offset=7, 
kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, 
kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, 
kafka_receivedTopic=trigger-fcm-notification, 
kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = trigger-fcm-notification, partition = 0, offset = 7, CreateTime = 1476864644264, checksum = 3680317883, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 270, key = null, value = common.vo.NotificationVo@203c8c95)
}
```

I need the value (NotificationVo) for further use in consumer. How to get it as part of payload?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDITED HERE:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
 xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

 <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka" />

 <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
  id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-template="template"
  auto-startup="true" channel="inputToKafka" topic="trigger-fcm-notification"
  order="1">

  <int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>
   <bean
    class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice" />
  </int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>
 </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

 <!--Producer-->
 <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
  <constructor-arg>
   <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
     <map>
      <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
      <entry key="retries" value="5" />
      <entry key="batch.size" value="16384" />
      <entry key="linger.ms" value="1" />
      <entry key="buffer.memory" value="33554432" />
      <entry key="key.serializer"
       value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" />
      <entry key="value.serializer"
       value="common.vo.NotificationVoSerializer" />
     </map>
    </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>


 <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
  id="kafka-inbound-channel-adapter-FCM" listener-container="container1" 
  auto-startup="true" phase="100" send-timeout="5000" 
  channel="ip-chanel-trigger-fcm-notification" mode="record"
  message-converter="messageConverter" />

 <bean id="messageConverter"
  class="org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter" />

 <int:service-activator input-channel="ip-chanel-trigger-fcm-notification"
  ref="fcmNotificationConsumer">
 </int:service-activator>

 <!--Consumer-->
 <bean id="container1"
  class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
  <constructor-arg>
   <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
     <map>
      <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
      <entry key="enable.auto.commit" value="false" />
      <entry key="auto.commit.interval.ms" value="100" />
      <entry key="session.timeout.ms" value="15000" />
      <entry key="group.id" value="trigger-fcm-notification" />
      <entry key="key.deserializer"
       value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
      <entry key="value.deserializer"
       value="common.vo.NotificationVoDeserializer" />
     </map>
    </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
  </constructor-arg>

  <constructor-arg>
   <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
    <constructor-arg name="topics" value="trigger-fcm-notification" />
   </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

This is the modified xml config file

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDITED HERE:

Consumer class:

```html
package common.notification.consumer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import common.vo.NotificationVo;

@Component
public class FcmNotificationConsumer {

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @ServiceActivator
 public <K, V> void process(Map<K, V> payload) {

  String topic = null;
  System.out.println("payload=====>"+payload.toString());

  for (K item : payload.keySet()) {
   topic = (String) item;
  }

  Object ackObject = payload.get(topic);
  System.out.println("ackObject=====>"+payload.get(topic));

 }
}
```

O/P:

```html
payload=====>{kafka_offset=21, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=trigger-fcm-notification, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = trigger-fcm-notification, partition = 0, offset = 21, CreateTime = 1476887227554, checksum = 222603853, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 270, key = null, value = common.vo.NotificationVo@29206bb8)}

ackObject=====>Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = trigger-fcm-notification, partition = 0, offset = 21, CreateTime = 1476887227554, checksum = 222603853, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 270, key = null, value = common.vo.NotificationVo@29206bb8)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDITED HERE:

Received expected payload after changing the method parameter in Consumer class.

```html
package common.notification.consumer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import common.vo.NotificationVo;

@Component
public class FcmNotificationConsumer {

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @ServiceActivator
 public void process(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("Message=====>"+message);
       Object payloadObject = message.getPayload();
   NotificationVo notificationVo = (NotificationVo) payloadObject;
 }
}
```

O/P:

```html
Message=====>GenericMessage [payload=common.vo.NotificationVo@4c144e99, headers={kafka_offset=16, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=trigger-fcm-notification, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = trigger-fcm-notification, partition = 0, offset = 16, CreateTime = 1476949945607, checksum = 2501578118, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 270, key = null, value = common.vo.NotificationVo@4c144e99)}]
```

Finally working as expected.

Thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: Oh! I've given you +1 since it is your first question, but looks like it isn't clear. What is `user own producer and consumer config`? Show some PoC and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Hi Bilan, 
Currently i am using spring-integration-kafka - 1.0.0 M2 and client kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0. 
Now upgrading this to spring-integration-kafka  - 2.1.0 release and client kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1
But when i updated all maven dependency it is giving problem to existing config.xml file  How to resolve this/

Comment: I will give up if we continue to play spy games. Are you really sure that this is useful and say something about `user own producer and consumer config` ?

Comment: Please, re-phase your question and consider to use `EDIT` option on the topic.

Comment: Updated my question with old config file, recently started looking into kafka. need help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Now it is more cleaner than before.

So, you current code is for Apache Kafka 0.8. Since version 0.9 it has fully different design. Therefore the current code for the Spring Integration Kafka 1.0 must be throw away.

You should read about Apache Kafka 0.10: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.

About Spring Kafka, which is based on the Kafka Client 0.10: http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/

And pay attention to the chapter there about Spring Integration Kafka: http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html

And note: nobody here is going to do work for you.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure why you say that you have a `payload` like that, because that is exactly `headers`. That `value` in the `ConsumerRecord` is converted to the `payload` of the message.

Please, share the code where you receive that and try to extract the `value`. The `<int-kafka:message-driver-channel-adapter>` produces `Message<>` with those `headers` and `payload` from the converted `ConsumerRecord` `value`.

Comment: Thank you for guidelines

Comment: Once resolved my issue completely will update here. Then please close the issue.

Comment: Hi, 
With above reference implemented the logic as per my requirement. 
I got small issue while reading the  Consumer Record .  
I got acknowledgement as follows, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = trigger-fcm-notification, partition = 0, offset = 7, CreateTime = 1476864644264, checksum = 3680317883, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 270, key = null, value = common.vo.NotificationVo@203c8c95)
I need the value (NotificationVo) for further use in consumer class. How to get this from acknowledgment?

Comment: Sorry, it isn't readable. Please, move it into your question and notify me about an edit. Also looks like you are talking about the `data`. Not sure how `Acknowledgment` is related here... You need `payload` and not that header to perform further business logic.

Comment: One more update  :
I am upgrading from version 9.0 to 10.0

Comment: I think you mean from `0.9.0` to `0.10.0`. Please, don't confuse us. We have a lot of other work to do...

Comment: Sorry for wrong update , yes i am upgrading from 0.9.0 to 0.10.0

Comment: Good, I see now. You know: there is no reason to replace the question content with the reason. Just an EDIT is good. I mean for traceability in the future and for the full picture.

Comment: Please, find an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Rephrased the question part

Comment: Sorry, doesn't help. You still show the old code. How about a new code for Kafka 0.10 ?

Comment: Ok, that's fine! But where is the code which treats those header as a payload?

Comment: In other words: everything is correct. Now let's concentrate on the logic of your `fcmNotificationConsumer`.

Comment: Hi Artem,
You are right, reading  headers instead of payload in Consumer class. Modified the method, received payload as expected. Will updated working code.
Thanks a lot for immediate response.

Comment: Please  consider the question as closed.